# Download image dynamically

Tags: image, xml-parsing, opencart

my supplier give me an xml file with all products and their images.

The images are hosted in the suplyer's DB and so in the xml folder appears like www.webservice.supplier.com/index.php?action=getimage&id=10

How can I download this image or use in my opencart system?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to open the file with file_get_contents, fopen or any other related php function. Once opened into a stream you can save it with the set of related functions (fwrite and such).

On to the details, this is some quick and dirty php code.

```
//This is the source image...
$url='http://www.google.es/logos/2013/womens_day_2013-1055007-hp.jpg';

$file=fopen($url, 'r'); //Check with your server's provider, just in case they won't allow you to do this.

if(!$file)
{
    die('ERROR: Could not read file');
}
else
{
    //This is where you'll store the file. Check the directory permissions.
    $destination=fopen('results/file_in_disk_.jpg', 'w');

    if(!$destination) die('ERROR: Could not create or open destination file');
    else
    {
        while($data=fread($file, 1024))
        {
            fwrite($destination, $data);
        }

        fclose($destination);
        fclose($file);
    }
}
```

The image provider is likely to be outputting image headers associated with that url, so don't worry if the source url doesn't look like an image.

Please, bear in mind that you should have your supplier's permission to download and use the images.

Hope that helps.

Edit: I forgot, you should wrap that code in some other piece that reads from the XML file and does its thing. Don't forget to check for already existing images!.

Comment: thanks a lot!it works great also if I have had to do a little tansformation to the file...so I go to the page www.webservice.supplier.com/index.php?action=getimage&id=10 and take the new url generated where the image appear and after copy that url and paste in your code

Comment: Last question: if I'd like to rename the image with the Id that appears in the url (www.webservice.supplier.com/index.php?action=getimage&id=10) how can i do?

Comment: sorry again..how can i do because are a lot of image?Of course I have the permission of mine supplier

Comment: Let's see. First, are you able to read the XML file using php?. If so, you should have no problem parsing the file and reading each image (and of course, renaming it). In case you don't know you should start trying to see if your server provider has a suitable XML parser installed. Let's try SimpleXML first... Take a look at these and tell me if you're having problems - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp.